# Anti-diagonal matrix operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-pde

Let $(A,\mathcal{D}(A))$ be an infinitesimal generator of a strongly continuous semigroup $(T(t))_{t\ge 0}$  on a Banach space $X$ and define on $\mathcal{X} := X \times X$ the
operator matrix
$$\mathcal{A}=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    0 & A \\
    A & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\right)$$

with domain $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A}) := \mathcal{D}(A) \times D(A).$

I want to know if $\mathcal{A}$ generates a strongly continuous semigroup on the product space $\mathcal{X}$.

Comment: I seems to me that your matrix is diagonal rather than anti-diagonal (as suggested in the title). Do you mean $\mathcal{A} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & A \\ A & 0 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: yeah exactly thank you that's what I meant.
 (The diagonal case is direct)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is *no* in general.

For a counterexample, let $A$ be your favourite semigroup generator that has a sequence of eigenvalues $(\lambda_n) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lambda_n \to -\infty$ (for instance, let $A$ be the Dirichlet or Neumann Laplace operator on $L^2(0,1)$).

If $f_n$ is an eigenvector for $\lambda_n$, then $(f_n,-f_n) \in \mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$ and $\mathcal{A}(f_n,-f_n) = -\lambda_n (f_n,-f_n)$. Hence, $\mathcal{A}$ has a sequence of eigenvalues that converges to $\infty$ and thus, it cannot be a semigroup generator.